# Is the Fourier series always the "best" approximation?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In Stein and Sharkachi's Introductory Fourier Analysis book, in Chapter 3, we're given the "Best Approximation Theorem".

The theorem implies (and almost states) that if $f \in L^2 (0,2\pi)$, then the "best" way to approximate $f$ by a sequence of trigonometric polynomials is precisely by the partial sums of its Fourier series.

Rigorously speaking,  if $a_N(\theta) = \sum_{|n| \leq N} b_n e^{in\theta}$ is any other sequence of trigonemtric polynomials, then $$||f-S_N(f)||_{L^2} \leq ||f-a_N||_{L^2} $$

My question is the following, is this true in any other norms? The most natural norms would to start with would be , of course, the $L^p$ norms.  I'm just curious how "canonical" are Fourier series in the approximation .

Comment: I have thought why they would say "if $f\in L^1[0,2\pi]$". After all, Fourier series is supposed to be defined for functions in $L^2[0,2\pi]$. A quick glance in the book shows that they are actually assuming $f$ is Riemann integrable! There is no Lebesgue integral in the book at all. Also keep in mind that Fourier series can converge in $L^2$ norm only to an $L^2[0,2\pi]$ function. There are some functions that are in $L^1[0,2\pi]$ but not in $L^2[0,2\pi]$, so there are certainly many functions in $L^1[0,2\pi]$ not approximable by Fourier series in $L^2$ norm.

Comment: Fourier series are not "supposed to be defined for functions in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ ".  The fourier series is defined so long as the defining integrals exist.  If $f \in L^1$ we certainly have the existence of the fourier series of $f$.  There is no lebesgue integral in the book, but this does not change the question.  I actually only mentioned it as to not discourage measure theoretic answers.  I'm interested in comparing how approximable functions are by their fourier series (if at all) with approximations by other sequences of trig polynomials with respect to any norm.

Comment: I edited it as to ensure that no one would think I'm suggesting $L^1 [(0, 2\pi)] = L^2([0,2\pi])$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No: the Fourier series is only best for the $L^2$ norm.  For a very simple example, consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,c]$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in[c,2\pi]$ (for some $c\in [0,2\pi]$) and consider just the first term of the Fourier expansion, which is $a=1-\frac{c}{2\pi}$.  This constant $a$ minimizes the $L^2$ norm $\|f-a\|_2$.  On the other hand, if we wanted to choose a constant $b$ which minimizes the $L^1$ norm $\|f-b\|_1$, we should choose $b=0$ if $c>\pi$ and $b=1$ if $c<\pi$ (for instance, if $c>\pi$, increasing $b$ above $0$ always just increases the $L^1$ norm since the integral on $[0,c]$ contributes more than the integral on $[c,2\pi]$).  So for $c\neq 0,\pi,2\pi$, we can get a better approximation than the Fourier expansion in the $L^1$ norm.

(More generally, the best constant approximation to a real-valued function is the mean value if you use the $L^2$ norm, but the median value if you use the $L^1$ norm.)

Comment: And the content of this answer can partly be viewed as an instance of the fact that there is a (true!) "minimization theorem" in Hilbert spaces, but not generally in Banach spaces (even in non-pathological situations). E.g., the "Dirichlet principle", as minimization problem in Banach spaces such as $C^o$, generally fails in both that existence and uniqueness can fail, easily, not pathologically. So "the best" approximation in a Banach space is not a-priori sensible...

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you! Your comment Paul, and your answer Eric were exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @paulgarrett Are you saying that usually minimization theorems don't occur in Banach Spaces?  Perhaps the same question, but are there sequences of trig polynomials that approximate Riemann integrable functions "best" in other $L^p$ norms, $p \neq 2$

Comment: The iconic contrast is that the finite partial sums of the Fourier series of an $L^2$ function best approximate it in $L^2$, while in the Banach space $C^o$ (from Baire category and its corollaries) typically the Fourier series can diverge at countably many points. But using Fejer's Cesaro-summed version gives a different sequence (_not_ the partial sums of the Fourier series!) of finite Fourier series which converge (uniformly) to $f\in C^o$.