# What is the difference working in $L^2$ and $C^2 $ for Fourier series expansion of functions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, fourier-analysis, online-resources

Once one of my lecturer said that if we worked in $L_2$, the complex inner product $$(u,v)=\displaystyle\int^L_0 u\ \bar v\ dx $$ works flawless for Fourier series, instead of working in $C^2$.

***Question:*** I do't see the general picture that what is the problem with working in $C^2$. I am taking differential equations under Mathematical Methods in Physics I (in my Physics department), so there is almost no rigor in our lectures, **I want to learn all the underlying idea Fourier series and this mentioned idea between $C^2$ and $L^2$. Any idea, comment, source, guidance, will be appreciated.**

Comment: One book I liked a lot for learning a bit more rigor behind all of the stuff I learned in Math methods was "Div, Grad, Curl, and all That"

Comment: [link](https://www.amazon.com/Div-Grad-Curl-All-That/dp/0393925161)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2621446/is-the-fourier-series-always-the-best-approximation

Comment: Also I'm slightly confused on your question.  I could be wrong but $\mathbb{C}^2$  is not the usual domain of fourier series for physicist.  Are you sure you don't mean $C^2$, the set of twice continuously differentiable functions?

Comment: I meant C^2 and wrote but someone changed editing

Comment: It is not clear what your lecturer meant. There is an isometry (may need scaling depending on your definition) between $L^2$ and $l_2$, which may be what she was referring to, but you give up (mostly, cf. Carleson's theorem) pointwise convergence niceties. Presumably in context you need pointwise convergence, so you need extra conditions on functions so the Fourier series converges in an appropriate way.

Comment: Another possibility is that it was mentioned that it is relatively easy to show that periodic $C^2$ functions have pointwise convergent Fourier series' but that, as mentioned, the isometry via standard hermitian products of periodic functions and sequences of Fourier coefficients extends to $L^2$ vs. $\ell_2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lecturer probably meant that the vector space $C^2([0,L])$, consisting of functions that are twice differentiable with continuous derivatives, is not [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) if equipped with the scalar product 
$$
\langle f| g\rangle= \int_0^L f(x)\overline{g(x)}\, dx.$$ 
Among the various unpleasant consequences of this, there's the Fourier series fact that if you take an arbitrary series 
$$
S(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}kx} $$ 
then, even if $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2<\infty $ (corresponding to the physical fact that $S$ has *finite energy*), you cannot conclude that $S\in C^2$. (In fact, it is not trivial to find conditions on $c_k$ that ensure $S\in C^2$. I don't think that a necessary and sufficient condition is known.)

On the other hand, the vector space $L^2([0, L])$, consisting of all measurable functions $f$ such that $\int_0^L |f(x)|^2\, dx<\infty$, is complete if equipped with the aforementioned scalar product $\langle\cdot|\cdot\rangle$. As a consequence of this, the finite energy Fourier series $S(x)$ always defines an element of $L^2([0, L])$. (Actually, all elements of $L^2([0, L])$ can be decomposed in a finite energy Fourier series.)

A good reference to be introduced to these things is the book by Stein and Shakarchi "Fourier analysis: an introduction", first volume.

Comment: You might mention explicitly that otoh it does follow that $S\in L^2$.